# Limiting SQL result with query

Tags: sql, google-ads-data-hub

I am trying to print the table results on the basis of output generated by another table.

so, lets say my table II produces an integer output of some value then I want to use that value to limit my results for table I.

I am unable to make this query work. I wrote this but cant see the problem.
Is there any other way of writing this?

I read somewhere on SO that subquery in limit is not allowed but I am not sure.

```
select * 
from stage_II_final_suzuki_1648155456      `  
limit ( select count(*)*0.80 
        from tmp.stage_II_final_suzuki_1648155456
      );
```

I want to correct the syntax for compiler

> ERROR> Failed validation Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [31:11]

Comment: Is this Google BigQuery, or some other DBMS?

Comment: I am trying to run this is Google's Ads Data Hub

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google Ads Data Hub uses BigQuery SQL. The syntax for LIMIT accepts a number (literal constant); you can't use any expression that needs evaluation.
It does support a ROW_NUMBER() function though, and you can try:

```
select *
from (
   select s1.*, row_number() over() as rn
   from stage_II_final_suzuki_1648155456 s1     `  
   ) s2
where  s2.rn <= ( select count(*)*0.80 
                  from tmp.stage_II_final_suzuki_1648155456
                 );
```

Comment: getting this ERROR: Failed validation Analytic function ROW_NUMBER cannot be called without an OVER clause at [32:21]

Comment: QUERY for reference: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iX9EcQGaviNUoZFxNY5bJ7/1

Comment: Added an OVER() clause

Comment: Failed: Unknown validation status Instance of 'minified:vA'

Comment: This error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the SQL syntax (sounds like it is related to your database instance).